# JAWR i18n: unit testing javascript when using messages

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, resourcebundle, jawr

Our application currently shares messages between the Java and Javascript side. They are stored as **resource bundles** in the class path, and we have a custom controller that returns all the messages as Json. The client side code look like this:

```
// This calls the controller to get all the messages
var messages = MessageBundle();
var text = messages.get('my.message', 1);
```

This is great because we can mock "messages" in our unit tests.

---

I want to start using **JAWR** for this, since we already use it for other things. The problem is JAWR [generates the following Javascript object](http://jawr.java.net/docs/messages_gen.html):

```
var text = messages.my.message(1);
```

This means the code **cannot be unit tested** anymore unless the unit tests also define a global "messages" variable with the right nested objects. Is there a way around this? Any idea how to extend JAWR to make this unit-testable?

Currently my work around is:

```
function messages() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var messageId = args.shift();
    var messageFunc = window.messages;        
    messageId.split('.').forEach(function(part) {
        messageFunc = messageFunc[part];
    });
    return messageFunc(args);
}

// Same syntax as the old one, but uses the JAWR object behind the scenes
// This function is easy to mock for a unit test
var text = messages('my.message', 1);
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe next samples can help you.

**1)**

```
function messagesTester(funcPath,id) {
  var args=funcPath.split('.'),root=window.messages;
  for(var i=0;i<args.length;i++)root=root[args[i]];
  return root(id);
  // or if more that one parameter for *func*, then, for example:
  // return root.apply(null,Array.prototype.slice(arguments,1));
}
var text = messagesTester('my.message',1);
```

**2)**

```
function messagesTester(funcPath) {
  var args=funcPath.split('.'),root=window.messages;
  for(var i=0;i<args.length;i++)root=root[args[i]];
  return root;
}
// var text = messagesTester('my.message')( /*arguments list*/ );
var text = messagesTester('my.message')(1);
```

Comment: Thanks. If I understand well, are these different implementations of the workaround? I like how #2 separates the arguments rather than using the first one as the ID and the rest as the parameters.


I was really hoping though for a way to change the way JAWR generates messages. It seems like a big overhead to process the "messages" object every time I want to read a string. Maybe JAWR could generate a hashmap of the message functions?

Comment: I'm not familiar with JAWR and cannot help you with _"way to change the way JAWR generates messages"_. I simply do showed for you some variants of _"your current workarround"_.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll have to do with this unless there is a way to configure JAWR differently. I might use your option 2) which looks more concise than mine, cheers.